# Подсказки pycharm

Tags: pycharm

Подскажите, как включить подсказки в pycharm для работы с html документами (в том числе и для конструкций типа `{{ }}`). Пробная про версия.

Answer (score 2):

Собственно проблема оказалась в том, что проект был создан в Community Edition. Создал проект в про версии, перенес файлы и подсказки заработали.